# How to remove styling automatically added by GoogleMaps API?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented GoogleMaps API, but the map doesn't appear on the screen.

I went into the inspect element tools and found that inline `style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"` was being added by GoogleMaps on the element with `<div id='map'>`.

When I manually deselect each styling attribute from the inspect tool, the map is placed in its proper position and is displayed on screen.

Is there anyway to remove the styling? And/ what would be the best method to do so?

## js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket;
  var map;
  var marker;
  var marker_locations = [];

  function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, lat, lng) {

      var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)};
      geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[0]) {

            //console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
            var address = results[0].formatted_address;
            //console.log(address);
            document.getElementById('id_address').value = address;
            //return address;

          } else {
            window.alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
  }

function getCurrentLocation() {
      // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
          {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            document.getElementById('id_lat').value = pos.lat;
            document.getElementById('id_lng').value = pos.lng;

            console.log(pos.lat);
            console.log(pos.lng);


            // draw map
            // set center to the currentPosition lat, lng
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: pos.lat, lng: pos.lng},
              zoom: 15,
            });


          marker_locations.push(pos);
          for(var i = 0; i < marker_locations.length; i++)
          {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker_locations[i].lat,marker_locations[i].lng),
              map: map,
            });


          }


        $("#map").append("<button id='requestValet' class='col-xs-12 waves-effect waves-light btn-large requestValetBtn light-blue darken-1' onClick='requestValet()'>Request Valet</button><div id='loading-screen'></div><div id='floating-button'><button onClick='updateCurrentLocation()' class='btn btn-success btn-md'>Ping Location</button></div>");

        $("#loading-screen").append("<div id='floating-loading-screen' class='col-xs-12'><div id='onscreen-message' class='col-xs-12'><h3>Finding Your Valet</h3><h4>Thanks for your patience</h4></div></div>");

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        geocodeLatLng(geocoder, pos.lat, pos.lng);

        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      }
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){

      connectSocket();
      getCurrentLocation();
  });
  </script>

  <div id='floating-panel'>

  <form action="{% url 'reparks:request' %}" class='col-xs-12' id='locationForm' method='POST'>
    <input id='id_address' type='text' name='address' placeholder='Enter your address'/>
    <input id='id_lat' type='hidden' name='lat' />
    <input id='id_lng' type='hidden' name='lng' />

  </form>

  </div>


  <div id="map" class="jumbotron jumbotron-map">

  </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your map initialization code? You shouldn't need to remove/modify the styles yourself

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but this app is built using Django+Angular.

Comment: Just to clarify, the map is working, but it flashes for 1 second, and then when the styling on the `<div id="map">` is appended, it is gone.